# Для чего создавать несколько доменов?

Tags: seo

Есть компания конкурентов, они занимаются мебелью, дверями, окнами. И у них на каждое направление свой домен, например: mebel-name.ru, okna-name.ru и тд. При чем сайты однотипные, только отличаются текстами и картинками.

Вопрос. Помогает ли это им в плане сео продвижения сайтов? Или почему они сделали так, а не иначе  (например один домен на котором были бы страницы под каждое их направление).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на это с другой стороны - если удаётся вывести все имеющиеся сайты в топ10 по нужным ключевикам, то мы вытесняем оттуда конкурентов.

Знаю несколько примеров из региональной выдачи городов-миллионников, когда по некоторым темам (мебель, посуточная сдача квартир, окна ПВХ) вебмастерам удавалось забить топ10 своими сайтами и конкуренты вынуждены были переходить на контекстную рекламу, чтобы хоть как-то заполучить трафик.

Другое дело, что таким образом вебмастера обрекают все сайты таких сеток на санкции, если все их сайты обнаруживаются и конкурентам-таки удаётся достучаться до Платона в Яндексе или техподдержки Гугла. Работая таким образом, нужно уникализировать всё - и контактные данные, и контент, и движки, не забывая размещать все сайты сетки на уникальные айпишники.

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то наличие ключевого слова в имени домена очень поднимало сайт в поисковой выдаче. Но те времена уже наверное лет десять как прошли. Сейчас это на выдачу не влияет, а размазывание контента на несколько доменов только ухудшает позицию сайта. Один большой сайт для поисковика ценнее, чем куча мелких сайтов, а разные домены он воспринимает именно как разные сайты.